# Date of install regular programs while installing system

Tags: user-data

I need to know how to find date of install program which was pre-installed in system. For example: How to find date of pre-installed `firefox`? I need to see the date it was installed on my system.

Comment: Do you mean the date it was originally included in the distro?  Or the date it was installed on your system?

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? I'm unclear on exactly what you are asking with "date of install program". Are you looking for date of release, date of installation or what? Please [edit] further information into your post. A review of [this](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) might help.

Comment: I need to know  the date it was installed on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the following:

`cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -B 2 firefox`

And it'll show you the dates of installations/upgrades/removals.  Note that if your log is very large, it will be rotated and archived in a file like `/var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz`

Unfortunately this doesn't show if it was installed during system installation.  This information is much harder to get.  You can view the modified date of the `firefox` binary, but that may have been modified afterwards, by an upgrade for example.

It's safe to assume that if it's not in the `history.log` files, that it was installed with the OS.  You can check a few things here.

First,

```
`sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep 'Filesystem created:'`
```

This will show you when the filesystem was created, but, if you reinstalled Ubuntu at some point and left the filesytem intact, it will still show the original date.  So this is not really good.

Second,

```
`ls -lt /var/log/installer`
```

will show oldest file on the bottom.  If the package is not in the very first `cat` command at the top of this answer, then it's safe to assume it was installed with the system, on the last date found using the `ls` command above.  Having the FileSystem date and the last date on the bottom of the `ls` command match, will confirm the date even more.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd try something based on grepping the (possibly compressed) dpkg log files e.g.

```
$ zgrep -h 'firefox:' /var/log/dpkg.log* | awk '$3 == "install"'
2016-04-20 22:11:24 install firefox:amd64 <none> 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
```

If you want to see install/upgrade history you can do

```
$ zgrep -h 'firefox:' /var/log/dpkg.log* | awk '$3 ~ /install|upgrade/' | sort -V
2016-04-20 22:11:24 install firefox:amd64 <none> 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
2016-06-30 05:13:54 upgrade firefox:amd64 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1 47.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2016-08-06 14:44:58 upgrade firefox:amd64 47.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2016-09-22 12:20:53 upgrade firefox:amd64 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 49.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2016-10-28 22:45:23 upgrade firefox:amd64 49.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 49.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
2016-11-19 04:04:10 upgrade firefox:amd64 49.0.2+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 50.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
2016-12-01 06:23:14 upgrade firefox:amd64 50.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2016-12-14 17:49:47 upgrade firefox:amd64 50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 50.1.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-01-28 06:17:13 upgrade firefox:amd64 50.1.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-02-07 02:17:49 upgrade firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
2017-03-08 05:34:34 upgrade firefox:amd64 51.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 52.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
2017-03-21 07:17:49 upgrade firefox:amd64 52.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 52.0.1+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

Comment: While this answer technically does work, it doesn't give as much information about the package.  For example, the package you're searching for could be a dependency of another package.  This answer would not indicate that, but doing `cat /var/log/apt/history.log | grep -B 2 firefox` will show `automatic` after the version number if it is a dependency.  This can be useful in many ways.